# Does device support change with AndroidX migration?

Tags: android, androidx

If I have a published android application that uses the android support libraries, and I then migrate my app to use androidx (making as few changes as possible), does this impact the needed OS on a device in order to run my app?

The AndroidX overview (https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/) states that "AndroidX ships separately from the Android OS and provides backwards-compatibility across Android releases. AndroidX fully replaces the Support Library by providing feature parity and new libraries." but I'm not sure that this answers my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AndroidX is designed as replacement for current support libraries. So it has same minimum api level, since version of support library 26.0.0 minimum api level is 14 (Android 4.0).

So if you had support library below 26 version in your project, AndroidX will impact on needed OS, in other case not.